# ios7 html5 audio tag with progress bar and volume control

Tags: html, audio, progress-bar, ios7

After Apple released IOS7, HTML5 audio tag UI is changed.

I want old style UI, new one is too simple and flat (without progress-bar and volume control).

Any idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom in on the page to reveal the audio controls instead.